# Error script giving the number with e+22

Tags: php, numbers

I have a PHP code that give number value to abox 
when i click at the number if he was high number like 10000000000000000000000
it giving me in the box (1e+22)
the code is:

```
echo "\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t<td class=\"val\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"text\" id=\"_tf";
    echo number_format($tid,0,'','');
    echo "\" name=\"tf[";
    echo number_format($tid,0,'','');
    echo "]\" value=\"0\" maxlength=\"100\"></td>\r\n\t\t\t<td class=\"max\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"_('_tf";
    echo number_format($tid,0,'','');
    echo "').value=";
    echo number_format($maxNumber,0,'','');
    echo "; return false;\">(";
    echo number_format($maxNumber,0,'','');
    echo ")</a><br>";
    echo number_format($maxNumber,0,'','');
    echo "</td>\r\n\t\t</tr>\r\n\t\t";
```

like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvDPU.png)

I want to give me the number without e+

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: This question is very hard to read. You need to provide the code that is actually causing the problem -- which I think is your Javascript. Trying to parse out what the output of the PHP file is and what that looks like when it ends up as Javascript and ***then*** trying to work out what the Javascript does is very difficult. And your Javascript seems to be obfuscated somewhat as well...

Comment: (Oh, and I fancy the answer to your question is that JS displays numbers over `10e21` in exponential notation.#

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. The number is being formatted in scientific notation. I *think* your PHP is outputting it as a string in normal notation thanks to your use of `number_format(x, 0, '.', '')` (it does on my PHP implemntation), so JavaScript code you haven't shown is reading that string as a number and then turning it back into a string, which formats it in scientific notation.

   To avoid that, pass the number to JavaScript as a *string*, and use the string. (You can also convert it to a number if you like to use it in a calculation, but beware #2 below.)
2. The number is **well** above the point at which even whole numbers are subject to precision issues in the number system JavaScript uses (IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point numbers). For instance, `9007199254740991` (aka `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`) and `9007199254740992` can be correctly represented, but they're the last ones where you can keep counting upward by just `1`; `9007199254740993` cannot be correctly represented. (If you add `1` to `9007199254740992`, you still get `9007199254740992`; to move past it, you have to add `2`. The further upward you go, the bigger those gaps get.) Your specific example is okay because it's one of the ones that can be correctly represented, but any calculation you do with it will be suspect because (for instance) `10000000000000000000000 - 1` is still `10000000000000000000000`. Heck, even `10000000000000000000000 - 457` is still `10000000000000000000000`, that's how far into the realm of imprecision it is.

You haven't quoted the code where the problem is, but for instance, this page correctly shows the number (and also shows it in scientific notation):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Show The Number</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$theNumber = 10000000000000000000000;
echo '<input type="text" value="' . number_format($theNumber, 0, '.', '') . '" id="foo">';
?>
<script>
var p = document.createElement("p");
// Get the *string* from the input
var numstr = document.getElementById("foo").value;
// Convert it to a number
var num = +numstr;
// Show both
p.innerHTML = "The number is " + numstr + " (" + num + ")";
document.body.appendChild(p);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u add it to the code that i post so i can cope it and past

Answer (score -1):

I found a js function for your scientific writing number,

```
// will return something as 1 12 123 1k 12k 0.1m [...]
function abbreviateNumber(value) {
    var formatedValue = value;
    if (value >= 1000) {
        var suffixes = ["", "k", "m", "b","t"];
        var suffixNum = Math.floor( (""+value).length/3 );
        var shortValue = '';
        for (var precision = 2; precision >= 1; precision--) {
            shortValue = parseFloat( (suffixNum != 0 ? (value / Math.pow(1000,suffixNum) ) : value).toPrecision(precision));
            var dotLessShortValue = (shortValue + '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
        if (dotLessShortValue.length <= 2) { break; }
    }
    if (shortValue % 1 != 0)  shortNum = shortValue.toFixed(1);
    formatedValue = shortValue+suffixes[suffixNum];
}
return formatedValue;
```

}

IQV is right, becareful to your tag, we are in js (php), but it doesn't matter.